# Grid problem - given a binary matrix (zeros - empty, ones -wall). How to determine the maximum volume of captured?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given some m by n grid of 1's and 0's, how would you find how much water would be captured by it, where the 1's are 'walls', and 0's are empty space?

**Examples:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This grid would capture 9 units of water.

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

However, because this grid has a 'leak' in one of its walls, this would capture 0 units of water.

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Likewise, because there is a partition between the two sections, the leaky one does not affect the other, and as such this grid would capture 3 units of water.

I'm just really uncertain of how to start on this problem. Are there any algorithms that would be helpful for this? I was thinking depth-first-search or some sort of flood-fill, but now I'm not sure if those are applicable to this exercise.

Comment: How did you determine the answers for these examples?  What is preventing you from implementing that in Python code?

Comment: So you want to identify the number of 0-elements centered in your matrix? A different, but very similar problem was [discussed in a mock interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tYoVx0QoN0) and might be a good starting point. In its current form, this question does not seem to be related to the `python` tag in specific and seems to be algorithm-related and language-agnostic.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question. Imagine that you're pouring water over the grid, with the walls keeping captured water in place and the empty space storing it. I'm not sure if I understand your second question. Can you clarify?

Comment: @albert Yeah, I basically want to find the number of 0-elements that are completely surrounded by walls. Now that I think about it, yeah, this question has nothing to do with any specific language at all. I just wasn't sure what to tag it with. Should I post this somewhere else, or are these types of questions alright?

Comment: You seem to be able to answer this question for the example grids you posted; how did you determine those answers?  Why can't the algorithm you used be translated into Python?

Comment: One observation/hint is that any empty space that is on the border of the grid cannot possibly hold water. Can you use this to determine which regions *will* hold water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of leaks starting from the positions of 0s on the edges. Then expand that list with 0s that are next to the leaking positions (until no more leaks can be added).  Finally, subtract the number of leaks from the total number of zeros in the grid.

```
def water(G):
    rows = len(G)
    cols = len(G[0])  
    # initial leaks are 0s on edges
    leaks = [ (r,c) for r in range(rows) for c in range(cols)
              if G[r][c]==0 and (r==0 or c==0 or r==rows-1 or c==cols-1) ]
    for r,c in leaks:
        for dr,dc in [(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)]: # offsets of neighbours
            nr,nc = r+dr, c+dc                    # coordinates of a neighbour
            if nr not in range(rows): continue    # out of bounds
            if nc not in range(cols): continue    # out of bounds
            if G[nr][nc] != 0: continue           # Wall
            if (nr,nc) in leaks: continue         # already known
            leaks.append((nr,nc))                 # add new leak
    return sum( row.count(0) for row in G) - len(leaks)
```

Output:

```
grid = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
print(water(grid)) # 9

grid = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
print(water(grid)) # 0

grid = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
print(water(grid)) # 3
```

*Note that this only looks for leaks in horizontal and vertical (but not diagonal) directions.  To manage leaking through diagonals, you'll need to add (-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1) to the list of offsets.*

Comment: Can we use `set` for `leaks` here instead?   Nice approach.  Upvote.

Comment: We could but we'd have to manage the while condition with a flag (or with a queue) because you can't add to a set while you're iterating on it. It would be more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

Removing zeros starting at the edges, representing the coordinates of zeros with a set (for fast lookup) of complex numbers (for easy neighbor calculation):

```
def water(G):
    m, n = len(G), len(G[0])
    zeros = {complex(i, j)
             for i in range(m) for j in range(n)
             if G[i][j] == 0}
    for z in list(zeros):
        if z.real in (0, m-1) or z.imag in (0, n-1):
            q = [z]
            for z in q:
                if z in zeros:
                    zeros.remove(z)
                    for a in range(4):
                        q.append(z + 1j**a)
    return len(zeros)
```

Or with Alain's style of a single BFS, initializing the queue with all edge zeros:

```
def water(G):
    m, n = len(G), len(G[0])
    zeros = {complex(i, j)
             for i in range(m) for j in range(n)
             if G[i][j] == 0}
    q = [z for z in zeros
         if z.real in (0, m-1) or z.imag in (0, n-1)]
    for z in q:
        if z in zeros:
            zeros.remove(z)
            for a in range(4):
                q.append(z + 1j**a)
    return len(zeros)
```

Comment: @DanielHao It's rather basic complex numbers usage, so besides something like Wikipedia's [Complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) page, I don't know what source to offer. If you mean the `1j**a`, that's just 1, i, -1, -i for the four angles.